# Dynamically update xml file with jinja2 placeholders with values stored in a separate yaml file using python

Tags: python, xml, jinja2

Might be beneficial for someone

Usecase:
Dynamically update xml configuration files from variables stored in a separate yaml file

File Structure:
I have multiple xml config files in a directory (service/configs/template(s).xml), each with multiple jinja2 placeholders. 1 file for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GatewayConfiguration>
    <LogCategory>{{log_category}}</LogCategory>
</GatewayConfiguration>
```

The variables are in a separate yaml file (service/variables/value_list.yml) - 1 example:

```
---
log_category: abc
```

Problem Statement:
during my AzDO pipeline runtime, I'm need to update the xml config files with the suitable variables utilizing the jinja2 substitution

Solution:

```
import os
import yaml
from jinja2 import Template

with open(r'/service/variables/value.yaml') as file:
  value_list = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

directory = os.listdir('/service/configs')
os.chdir('/service/configs')

for file in directory:
  with open(file, 'r+') as open_file:
    read_file = open_file.read()

    template = (read_file)
    j2_template = Template(template)
    print(j2_template.render(value_list))
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: No problem @balderman --- but a readymade solution for anyone who might be needing to update multiple xml templates with jinja2 vars stored in a separate file

Comment: stackoverflow is a place where you ask a question and the community tries to help you. This is how it works.